# authorization on the app store site through the program

Tags: c#, cookies, app-store, webclient

I want to automate the upload of data from my account. But I can not enter. I have all the information on the outgoing request (cookie, username, password)

I use WebClient:

```
var url = "https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login";
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("accountName", "####");
webClient.QueryString.Add("password", "####");
var data = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", webClient.QueryString);
var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Error: Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

I use cookies:

```
var values = new NameValueCollection
{                    
    {"acn01","####"},
    {"ccl", "####"},
    {"itcdq", "####"},
    ...
    {"wosid", "####"}
};
client.UploadValues(@"https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login", values);

Error:  Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Used request from chrome:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/#/apps?t=apps&interval=r&datesel=d30");
request.Headers["Host"] = "analytics.itunes.apple.com";
request.Headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive";
request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
    request.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "uk-UA,uk;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6";
    request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0";
    request.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
```

It works, but I’m getting a sitpage that my browser doesn’t support

Can someone tell me how to log in? Thank